# How to combine two dataframes with different types of index(one is DatetimeIndex, the other is PeriodIndex)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have encountered an error when pd.concat two dfs  with different types of index(one is DatetimeIndex, the other is PeriodIndex).

**df1.index:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07'...],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2022, freq=None)
```

**df2.index:**

```
PeriodIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06',
             '2010-01-07'...],
            dtype='period[B]', name='Date', length=2304, freq='B')
```

**Error message:**

```
 'Index' object has no attribute 'freq'
```

**Self attempt:**

didn't work when modify the freq='B' in df1.index or remove freq from df2.index

Comment: Do you want to concat by row or column?

Comment: by row, so pd.concat([df1,df2],axis = 1)

Answer (score 1):

You need same types in both, so need [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) or [`PeriodIndex.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.to_timestamp.html):

```
d = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07'])

p = pd.PeriodIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06',
             '2010-01-07'], dtype='period[B]', name='Date',  freq='B')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':0}, index=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':1}, index=p)

#if need output PeriodIndex
df1.index = df1.index.to_period('B')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)

              a  b
2010-01-01  NaN  1
2010-01-04  0.0  1
2010-01-05  0.0  1
2010-01-06  0.0  1
2010-01-07  0.0  1
```

---

```
#if need output DatetimeIndex
df2.index = df2.index.to_timestamp()
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)

              a  b
2010-01-01  NaN  1
2010-01-04  0.0  1
2010-01-05  0.0  1
2010-01-06  0.0  1
2010-01-07  0.0  1
```